# Laravel 5.4 - instanceof Collection not returning true when being passed what seems to be a Collection

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm working with a method that does an `instanceof Collection` check:

```
if ($group instanceof Collection) {
    $group = $group->pluck('name');
}
```

This is being used in many places, so I am not able to change it (not that I want to), but I do want to pass in a collection of group names. I'm instantiating my collection like so:

```
$group = collect(['one', 'two', 'three']);
```

When I `dd` the $group variable it looks a duck,

```
Collection {#612
  #items: array:3 [
    0 => "one"
    1 => "two"
    2 => "three"
  ]
}
```

but returns false in that instanceof check. Any ideas why this might be so?

Comment: Can you show the `use` statement for the `Collection` please? It should be at the top of the file.

Comment: `use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is that the `instanceof` is checking for an instance of Eloquent's extension of `Collection`.

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection;
```

If you change your `use` the base collection class, it should work:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
```

Answer (score 2):

There are (at least) two different types of `Collection` classes in Laravel:

- Illuminate\Support\Collection
- Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection

Check this code:

```
$collection = collect([1, 2, 3]);
dd(
  $collection instanceof Collection,
  $collection instanceof Illuminate\Support\Collection,
  $collection instanceof Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection
);
```

In this case, the return I get is

```
false // Collection
true  // Illuminate\Support\Collection
false // Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection
```

So, using `collect()` creates an instance of `Illuminate\Support\Collection`, but the version of `Collect` that's available (or included with a `use` statement) is not the correct one.